# Converting a ResourceSet of bitmaps into a sorted List<float>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a map. It can be zoomed-in and out. At first, I used one large image. Scrolling the mouse wheel defined the desired zoom level. Every scrolling created a new instance of the image in the desired dimensions. This approach was horribly slow.

So I gave up the possibility of zooming into any level, and created a list of predefined available zoom levels, ranging from 35% to 100% with 5% intervals, and then up to 300% with 50% intervals. For each zoom level, I have created a copy of the original image with the appropriate dimensions. The image name corresponds to its dimensions, so a 35% image is called "35.jpg". I added the images to the project's resources in a dedicated folder. Visual Studio automatically inserts an underline before the object's name because it starts with a number, so the object that represents the file is called "_35". So now, after the desired zoom level has been determined by the mouse wheel, the corresponding image is loaded from the resources. Performance has improved significantly.

Some of the application's components need a list of all available zoom levels. For example, for a `ComboBox` that allows the user to select a specific zoom level, rather than reach it through the mouse wheel. Therefore, when loading the form, a `List<float>` is initialized with all available zoom dimensions, so a 35% zoom is saved as 0.35 (a floating point representation is required by most components that uses the list) . The initialization is done by importing the names of the objects from the resources.

Here is the method that extracts file names and parse them into `float`. I feel it is not well written but I cannot point to a specific problem. I would love to hear your opinion. Thanks!

```
private static void InitializeZoomFactorsList()
{
    ResourceSet images = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    List<string> names = images.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(item => item.Key.ToString()).ToList();
    List<float> factors = names.ConvertAll<float>(delegate(string i) { return float.Parse(i.Substring(1, i.Length - 1)) / 100; });
    factors.Sort(); // because the list was strings, 300 came before 90, so after the parsing, I sort it by the value.
    zoomFactorsList = factors;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working code? There are not enough `}`. A copy/paste error or is this just pseudocode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's try to make it more concise:

```
var zoomLevels = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager
    .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(x => ParseZoomLevelAndNormalize(x.Key))
    .OrderBy(x => x);
```

Note that you do not need to create multiple temporary lists (not that you will ever note this waste) using `ToList()`. Also note that *parsing* code has been moved to a separate function. Let's talk about that...

```
static float ParseZoomLevelAndNormalize(object resourceName)
{
    string zoomLevel = Convert.ToString(resourceName).Substring(1);

    return Single.Parse(zoomLevel,
        NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100;
}
```

If you do not thin it's clear enough then you should introduce separate functions to explain what it is doing:

```
var precalculatedMaps = new PrecalculatedMaps();
var zoomLevels = precalculatedMaps.ZoomLevels.Select(x => x / 100);
```

Where `PrecalculatedMaps` hides the implementation detail (now it's a resource file, in future might be a folder in file system). `ZoomLevels` property simply return a *standard* `IEnumerable<float>` of available zoom levels (in range [0...100]). Proof of concept:

```
sealed class PrecalculatedMaps
{
    public IEnumerable<float> ZoomLevels
    {
        get
        {
            if (_zoomLevels == null)
                _zoomLevels = ReadAvailableZoomLevels().OrderBy(x => x);


            return _zoomLevels;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<float> _zoomLevels;

    private static IEnumerable<float> ReadAvailableZoomLevels()
    {
        return Properties.Resources.ResourceManager
            .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
            .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
            .Select(x => ParseZoomLevel(x.Key));
    }

    private static float ParseZoomLevel(object resourceName)
    {
        string zoomLevel = Convert.ToString(resourceName).Substring(1);

        return Single.Parse(zoomLevel,
            NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Note that here I made few assumptions which you can't ignore:

- Resource names are *valid* numbers (otherwise `Single.Parse()` will throw an exception).
- Numbers are formatted using en-US locale. In your code you're parsing using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (the default if you do not specify any `IFormatProvider`). For integer numbers you will probably never have trouble but it's *better* to be sure, right?
- There is always a leading underscore (that might be VS default but you can change resource name by hand). Do you want to handle the case? Change `.Substring(1)` with `.TrimStart('_')`.
- If you have only natural numbers then you can use `NumberStyles.Integer` instead of `NumberStyles.Number` (which allows decimals).

---

OK, that was about your actual code but let me say few words about the *algorithm*. Zooming an image is not an incredibly slow operation, I don't know how you did it and which technology you use for UI then I can't give you better ideas but:

- You **limit zooming** to integer factors.
- You can **cache** those generated images.
- You can **generate images only at special thresholds** (for example 200%, 50%, 25%) leaving the exact scale in/out duty to **UI controls** (which are pretty good at this). This might not be applicable if your zoom algorithm is REALLY slow and undoubtedly better than *canonical* decimation/interpolation algorithms already in use.
- You can **debounce** zoom requests to do not generate hundreds images when user is zooming from 100% to 10% and he's not interested in the intermediate images (leaving the duty to scale things to UI controls).

Comment: This answer should get one thousand upvotes.

Comment: @Sipo thank you but it's not that _special_! Especially second part is more "Stack Overflow style" than "Code Review style". If you post a new question with code you're using for zooming the image then we may TRY to _polish_ it little bit, maybe it will work in _real-time_ without any trick with pre-computed imaged.